# Why does this regular expression testing always return NO?

Tags: objective-c, regex

I use the following regular expression:

```
NSString *reg1 = @"/[$|§|%|&|{|}|'|`|´|^|°|~]/i";

NSPredicate *messageTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@",
                           reg1];
```

And I test if the string matches this regex:

```
if([messageTest evaluateWithObject:message] == NO){
        messageValid = NO;
        NSLog(@"message invalid");
}
```

So if the text contains any of the characters that are specified in the regular expression the text is invalid.

This regex worked for me in javascript. However in objective-c I get always NO regardless of what characters are in the string.

Where is the problem?

Comment: What is the object 'message'?

Comment: Is your regular expression library Unicode safe? Have you forgotten to escape any characters, particularly `{` and `{` that are special? Should you really use a regexp to look for a character in a set of 10? There are likely simpler ways.

Comment: What do you mean with regex library? My code is straigt from cocoa I don't use any library. What do you mean with escape? I get a message as string and want to test for the given chars. What is the simpler way`?

Comment: Why do you have pipes in your character set? They are not necessary to `OR` characters inside of `[]`

Comment: Braces `{}` are often used for quoting or grouping in regexps so need to have their specialness removed (sometimes with a backslash). You are using a regexp library which is in Cocoa, it just isn't visible to you. As for the best way to do it in Objective-C, dunno but in C I'd use `strpbrk(s, "$§%&{}'\`´^°~")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are essentially two problems with your code. Firstly, your regular expression

```
NSString *reg1 = @"/[$|§|%|&|{|}|'|`|´|^|°|~]/i";
```

is wrong:

- ICU regular expressions do not use /pattern/modifier. Also, why would you specify a case-insensitive match for that character set?
- ICU regular expressions need the following characters to be quoted: `$` `{` `}` `^`
- As ridgerunner mentioned, do not use `|` to separate characters in a character class.

The ICU regular expression you want is

```
[\$§%&\{\}'`´\^°~]
```

Try this in your program:

```
NSString *reg1 = @"[\\$§%&\\{\\}'`´\\^°~]";
```

(note that the `\` character is represented as `\\` in an Objective-C string.)

Secondly, you’re testing

```
if([messageTest evaluateWithObject:message] == NO)
```

to check whether a message is invalid. But `-evaluateWithObject:` returning `NO` means that there **wasn’t** a match, hence the string doesn’t contain any of those characters, hence the string **is** valid. You need to change that to its opposite, namely:

```
if([messageTest evaluateWithObject:message])
```

which means that there **was** a match, hence the string contain at least one of those characters, hence the string **isn’t** valid.

Answer (score 1):

- In a character class, do not separate characters with the `|` character. A character class can match only one character and the char class is simply a list of what that one character may be. (See: [Character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html))
- I don't know objective C, but my guess is that you don't want the `/` delimiters. I think this is probably your main problem.
- Your question is not clear. Do you want to check if any one of the characters in the string matches, or do you want to make sure that all of the chars in the string match or do you want to see if none of the characters match or what?

That said try this which corrects a couple of the problems:

```
NSString *reg1 = @"[$§%&{}'`´^°~]";
```

Comment: I edited my question,I also edited the regular expression which was wrong.